# Can I set up an alert for when resource locks are deleted?

Tags: azure, security

I'm trying to set up an alert for when the lock on my Logs Analytics Workspace is deleted

I have set up my Logs Analytics Workspace to send its **Audit Logs** to itself

When I delete a lock, and then do a query on the Operation table, I cannot see any records relating to the lock deletion. I can see records relating to the data limit being set and updated though

Is there any way to set up an alert to let me know when someone has deleted a lock on a resource? Specifically, on a Logs Analytics Workspace resource?